# Does g(n) = O(f(n)) imply g(n^2) = O(f(n^2))?

Tags: big-o

I have been stuck on a problem for a while, and I would like to know if g(n) = O(log n), does g(n^2) = O(log n^2)? I would like to know whether I can apply this method to solve the aforementioned problem.

The problem in question (for context only):

If f(n) = n * g(n^2) and g(n) = O(log n), prove that f(n) = O(n log n).

Comment: I think the confusion here stems from the use of `n` as some hand-wavy "it means the input size or something" variable, with no real structure. The `n` in `g(n)` is presumably the input data for some function `g`. But then you equate it to `O(log n)`, in which context `n` looks like the input size (of the input... `n`?). Imagine rewriting it this way: if `g(input)` = `O(log(size(input))`, then does `g(someLargerInput) = `O(log(size(someLargerInput))`? Then the answer is clearly yes

Comment: Use [the formal definition of big-O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation). This will introduce some constants into an expression, which you can then rearrange.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is yes: *n* is just a number, and so is *n<sup>2</sup>*. Imagine if you call *a = n<sup>2</sup>*, then isn't *g(a)* still *O(log(a))*?

Your confusion is that in fact, *O(log(n<sup>2</sup>)) = O(2 log n) = O(log n)*. This follows from the properties of the logarithm.

To illustrate, for your specific problem, we have that: If

*g(n) = O(log n)*

then

*g(n<sup>2</sup>) = O(log(n<sup>2</sup>)) = O(2 log n)) = O(log n).*

And since

*f(n) = n * g(n<sup>2</sup>)*

then clearly

*f(n) = O(n log n)*. □

(The amount of rigor your proof requires would depend on the context of your course or book.)